# Numpy: Efficient way of finding the index of the element in an array with the smallest value given an index array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have a numpy array `a = np.array([1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7])`. Now I have another numpy array `b = np.array([-1, -2, 3, 2, -1, -3])`. The length of `b` is smaller than or equal to `a`. I wanna find the index `i` of the smallest element in `a` such that `b[i] > 0`. So in the example above, the result will be `3` since according to `b` only indices `2, 3` are valid and `a[2] == 3` and `a[3] == 2`, so index `3` is chosen.

My current solution is

```
    smallest = np.inf
    index = None
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i] > 0:
            if(a[i] < smallest):
                smallest = a[i]
                index = i
```

I am not sure if I can use numpy to do it more efficiently. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one vectorized way -

```
In [72]: idx = np.flatnonzero(b>0)

In [73]: idx[a[:len(b)][idx].argmin()]
Out[73]: 3
```

Comment: What's the purpose of that `[:len(b)]`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Was because `a` could be bigger than `b`, but then with `idx` being decided by `b`, I figured later, `idx` can't have indices larger than `len(b)`, so isn't really needed for that specific case.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought maybe it's some clever optimization I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intermediate results of indices from b to get the right index later, heres a way.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7])
b = np.array([-1, -2, 3, 2, -1, -3])

indices_to_check = np.where(b > 0)[0]
result = indices_to_check[np.argmin(a[indices_to_check])]
#Output:
3
```

Answer (score 0):

one liner:

```
idx = np.argwhere(a==a[:len(b)][b>0].min())[0]
```

Understandable code:

```
shortened_a = a[:len(b)]
filtered_a = shortened_a[b>0]
smallest = filtered_a.min()
indices_of_smallest = np.argwhere(a==smallest)
first_idx = indices_of_smallest[0]
```

Comment: It is code efficient. To figure out if it is computationaly efficient, you should always profile. But generally speaking, python `for` loops with dynamic type detection don't beat numpy C code with typed data.